# switching tabs programmatically android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have two tabs reports and charts. In charts tab i have another activity 'graph' being shown on click of a button. Now when in 'graph' activity, on click of a button, i want to switch to the reports tab an not come back to the charts tab.

So in activity 'graph' I thought i should do this,

```
final TabHost tabHost =  (TabHost) getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabHost);
    btnBackToReports.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        }
    });
```

This probably would work if the tabhost was being created in the xml of the TabActivity class. But I'm not create the tabhost in the xml. So, I cannot do `findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost)`. I'm creating it in the java file like this,

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec chartsSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("charts").setIndicator("Charts")
                                    .setContent(new Intent(this, Charts.class));
                                    tabHost.addTab(chartsSpec);
```

So how do i now get the id of the tabHost? Is it possible to set an ID to tabHost programmatically?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you guys, for your response. But I've changed the design. The reason i had this 'graph' activity was because I didnt know it was possible to hide the tab bar. Now that I have found that I can hide the tab bar, I have removed the 'graph' activity all together. Now I am doing all the stuff of the 'graph' activity in the Charts tab itself. Since I can hide the tab bar, I get enough space in charts tab to do this. so on click of back button in charts tab which is now in full screen mode, I can switch to another tab and replace the tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, there are many solutions for this.

Variant 1) (removed, was stupid)

Variant 2)
you could send a Broadcast from the activity which want to change the tab, to the activity which host the tab and in the Broadcast Receiver you have access to the tabhost.

Comment: Variant 1 will cause memory leaks, as the View and activity context will still be available after the activity is destroyed.

Comment: yes, you are right. that's why I marked it "not so nice". I removed it, before someone use this bad code... :-/

Comment: Variant 2 does look like it could be the potential solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the UI of one Activity from another (well, it might be *possible*, but don't try it).

The best option would be to use `startActivityForResult` when starting your graph activity.
Then when someone clicks your button, you can do

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("selected_tab", 1);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}
```

and in your activity with the tabs

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        int selectedTab = intent.getIntExtra("selected_tab", 0);
        if (selectedTab == 1) {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't trying to change the UI. I only wanted to switch to a different tab instead of the parent tab that had called the activity. Your suggestion does seem very promising and very simple to implement, thank you.

Comment: Hmm in that case, you can probably pass a reference (to the parent Activity) to the child activity in the tabs, then when you click the button in the child activity call some method on the parent activity you got passed.